# Fit borders of an UIImageView objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

I made an App and I am detecting a collision with this imageView:

[image]

So, the problem is that I would like the frame "to fit " with the actual Ufo size/ borders. At the moment there is just a rectangle around it, like the normal frame of the UIImage.

Is there a way to do it?
(Im programming in Objective -C)

Kind Regards

Comment: Why not use sprites for this? i think sprites are made for detecting this behaviours and attributes as it fits perfectly with the images you give

Comment: well , the app is done and already in the App Store:D i don't want to rewrite it completely to change it :( Or can i just make a sprite for that only and it may work ?

Comment: is there no way to do it without the sprite kit:(

Comment: I dont think so, you can use beizerpath to create an imageview according to the image but you should know your image bounds from before hand then and its very heavy coding.